# rxjs Subscribe but don't need all to emit

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators

When I subscribe to an observable stream I want to combine, but they don't both need to emit.

Any idea how to achieve this or what RxJs operator I can use?

```js
// function in a service
getContent(): {
  return CombineLatest({
    list: of([ {...} ]) // always want this to be emitted
    ignore: of( null ), // subscribe but don't care if it's emitted or not.
  }).pipe(
     map(({ list }) => list // always return the list response
  )
}
```

In my specific case I want to stream to content from the store and on the side I also want to listen for web socket updates. And this would be done in one subscribe.

Note: the ignore stream is responded to via a tap outside of this example (it's listening to webSockets for updates). The list is a stream of content from my ngRx store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a merge with a filter

```
merge(of([ {...} ]), of( null ).pipe(filter(() => false)))
```

It will filter out all emission so it will never contribute to the merge.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is better than using  `combineLatest`.

Comment: Yeah merge is what I used. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to return an observable that emits some data (`a$`), and want to maintain a subscription for some other observable (`b$`) for as long as there is a subscription to `a$`.

You could achieve this behavior like this:

```js
getContent() {
  const voidB$ = b$.pipe(
    filter(() => false),  // prevent all emissions
    startWith(undefined)  // start by emitting 'undefined'
  );

  return combineLatest([a$, voidB$]).pipe(([a]) => a);
}
```

Here, we use `filter` to filter out all emissions from `b$` and use `startWith` to initially emit `undefined`.  So the `combineLastest` will emit whenever `a$` emits while maintaining the subscription to `b$`.

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this? when (and only when) `list$` emits, it also takes previous value from `b$`

```
list$.pipe(
   withLatestFrom(b$.pipe(startWith(undefined), skip(1)))
).map( ... )
.subscribe()
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom

Comment: Would this work if "b$" doesn't emit?

Comment: @Ewan I think the value is `undefined` then if has emitted 0 values or it is completed, but not sure. but the entire thing only listens mainly `list$`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Reading a comment in the link I see  "//both sources must emit at least 1 value"

Comment: @Ewan You can bypass this by doing `b$.pipe(startWith(undefined), skip(1))`.
Then it thinks that it has already emitted at least value. But of course, the value will be undefined unless something else is emited